# Xamarin Forms (C#) - Call to Navigation.PushModalAsync throws a Null Reference exception when called from Picker.SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm somewhat new to Xamarin Forms.
I'm trying to get a page to load when the Picker's selectedIndex changes.

Whenever I invoke the PushModalAsync line from Entry.TextChanged, I have no problems.
But when I try to invoke the same line from Picker.SelectedIndexChanged, I get a null reference error.
Here is the code I have implemented for the Picker.SelectedIndexChanged.

```
private void VariationPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (variationPicker.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        var result = results.Find(s => { return variationPicker.Items[variationPicker.SelectedIndex] == s.variantName; });
        variationPicker.Unfocus();
        var page = new NavigationPage(new StockConfirmationPage(currentBinrack, currentBarcode, result));
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page));
    }
```

From applying breakpoints in my code, I've found that the error occurs in the PushModalAsync method.
I'm finding it difficult to debug as the code is multi-threaded.
I have eliminated the StockConfirmationPage as the cause of the issue by using an empty content page instead and I get the same error.

Any idea why this would happen?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition) and developing for Android

Comment: I have the following dialog in the Output window when the Application is in Break-Mode:

01-31 06:30:47.955 I/MonoDroid(12038):
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRendererBase`1+<>c__DisplayClass10_0[TControl].<Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IPickerRenderer.OnClick>b__0 (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x00021] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\PickerRenderer.cs:128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured out the problem.
It actually had nothing to do with the PushModal method.
The reason I would get the error on this line is that the error was actually occuring when the Picker_Unfocused event handler finished.

The problem appears to be the invocation of:

```
variationPicker.Unfocus();
```

After replacing this with

```
locationNameLabel.Focus();
```

it began working as intended. I assume I could have focused any element in the content page. Just don't directly unfocus the picker to avoid this problem.

I'm interested in the reason why this happens, if anyone knows?

Comment: According to your code, I think you don't set variationPicker.Unfocus(), why you do this? And I search some info, but still don't find info about this issue, if you solved your issue, please remember to mark you reply as answer, thanks.